# How to Decrypt data in SFMC coming from API call from external system in Encrypted format

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

If data records are coming to SFMC Data Extension via API calls. And this data is encrypted by external system. I want to decrypt that data and store it in SFMC DE.

How can I do it?

Also, I am not finding any documentation regarding how to get "Marketing Cloud Public Key" which can be used to encrypt the data to be sent to SFMC via API calls?

Comment: Can you specify REST or SOAP please?

Comment: Data is coming to SFMC via REST API.

Comment: It may be possible with the [DecryptSymmetric()](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/DecryptSymmetric.htm) AMPScript function.  It's been done the other way -- encrypted in SFMC and decrypted outsde if SFMC.  It'll involve a lot of trial and error and possibly some flexibility in the encryption used in the external system.

Comment: Oh and welcome back to SFSE, @Timothy!  Long time, no see!

Comment: Thanks for your response @Adam. I had gone through DecryptSymmetric() AMPScript, but I could not get much information related to how can external system like C# or PHP encrypt some data and I can decrypt that data in SFMC using AMPScript DecryptSymmetric().

Comment: @AdamSpriggs, Thank you.  New re-org, new role, and I can finally be a regular again.

Comment: @Timothy https://giphy.com/gifs/excited-yes-victory-uTuLngvL9p0Xe

Comment: I'm also having trouble with this as well. It seems there's no way for AMPScript to recognize you're passing it Base64 character data if you're importing it from outside. I've tried to nest statements with no success: Base64Encode(Base64Decode(RequestParameter('payload')))

Comment: @AdamSpriggs Can you share any examples of decrypting data outside of marketing cloud that was encrypted using encryptsymmetric() ampscript function?